# Order of Aut$(D_4)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How can I prove that order of Aut$(D_4)$ is 8.
Let we show $D_4$ as $\{e,\sigma,\sigma^2,\sigma^3,\tau,\tau\sigma,\tau\sigma^2,\tau\sigma^3\}$ and $\quad\sigma^4=e=\tau^2,\quad\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma^3$. 
I Know that if $f\in$ Aut$(D_4)$ then

1. $f(e)=e$
2. $f(\sigma)=\sigma\quad or\quad \sigma^3$
3. $f(\tau)=\tau\quad or\quad \tau\sigma\quad or\quad \tau\sigma^2\quad or\quad \tau\sigma^3$

Now what can I do?

Comment: $f(\sigma) = \sigma^2$ is not an option, since $\sigma^2$ has order $2$. Hint: The map will be uniquely determined by the image of $\sigma$ and $\tau$, so you just need to show that they all yield automorphisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here you can bash it out the old-fashioned way. Since automorphisms preserve order and there is a unique cyclic subgroup of order $4$ you could consider the automorphism which switches those two generators, and see where everything else would have to go to. Note that all automorphisms of the whole group fix (not necessarily pointwise) this subgroup because it is characteristic, so you cannot have weird behavior like $\sigma^2\mapsto \tau$.

Now since $\sigma,\tau$ generate the group, we need only specify the values on these elements.

The order $2$ are $\tau\sigma^i,\;0\le i\le 3$, which gives $4$ choices, and we have already seen there are only two choices for $\sigma$, giving a total of $8$ possibilities since you can choose the values of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ **independently**. By enforcing the homomorphism condition, you can verify they're all bijective homomorphisms which are well-defined.